# DetailsView separator image between two rows

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to use DetailsView of asp.net to display data in the following format:

Name:      Adam

Age:       18

Gender:    M

And I wanted to add a lines (gray image) between each two rows

(something like:)

Name:      Adam

---

Age:       18

---

Gender:    M

I managed to put the image as another row between each two rows, but it make it start only on the second column (of the data) because the first column "saved" for the header (which is empty)

anyone knows how can put the image between the rows and make it "use" the whole line?

P.S

I did what I did using:

```
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <img src="../Images/thin_grey_separator.png" alt=""/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to accomplish this task by a manipulation the styles:

```
<style type="text/css">
    tr.spacer td { padding-bottom: 10px; }
</style>

<asp:DetailsView ...>
    <RowStyle CssClass="spacer" />
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Comment: no, it's not working. Can you post an example of this idea that worked? (maybe I did something wrong)